# Object formation with relationships(JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, dao

There are 3 entities (which matches tables):

```
public class Enterprise{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private List<Department> departments;

  //getters()/setters()
  }

public class Department{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private List<Employee> employees;

  //getters()/setters()
  }

public class Employee{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private List<Department> departments;

  //getters()/setters()
  }
```

ENTERPRISE---|*OneToMany*|---DEPARTMENT---|*ManyToMany*|---EMPLOYEE

**Can someone write method on JDBC** :

```
List<Enterprise> findAll();
```

The connection, statements, queries, etc. can be ignored. The main difficulty is to set all references on the correct objects (for example, to avoid:
**enterprise.getDepartments().get(1).getEmployees().get(1).getDepartments() == NULL**) .

**EXAMPLE (The beginning of method):**

```
 List<Enterprise> findAll(){
    ResultSet rs = executeQuery(SELECT_ALL_ENTERPRISES);
            List<Enterprise> ents = createEnterprises(rs);
                .........
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to do this with JDBC and not with JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping objects to relations is not as easy as it would seem.  They have been working on it for decades now, with decent results only in *some* scenarios.  The good news is that the scenarios that work can accommodate most programs.

I suggest that you take a different approach, but first I'll give you an example that will help you understand why I suggest the different approach.

Imagine a person who wants to look up all Departments, which will require a look up of all Employees (as they are part of a Department object).  Which will require that for each employee, a list of departments would need to be looked up, which would require that those departments would need a list of employees, which would ....

Perhaps now you get the idea.

So many systems that are structured like yours don't actually return full `Employees` when looking up departments.  They return "Employee identifiers".  This allows one to look up all the Departments, but it guarantees that no Employees are going to be returned, preventing an infinite loop.  Then, if a person is interested enough, they can use the employee identifiers to look up individual employees, which would of course contain department identifiers.

In short, I recommend that you don't really rebuild the association at this level.  I suggest that you build disconnected graphs of the object mesh, such that one can easily navigate the disconnected graph at a later time.  Then, if you really must connect them, you will at least have all the data loaded without recursion before you start knitting together references.

Answer (score 0):

Many ORM libraries enable you to define one to many relationships as you described. Sormula can do this. See [one to many example](http://www.sormula.org/onetomany/).

What I like about Sormula is that if you name the foreign key field on the "many side" the same as the field "one side", then Sormula will deduce the relationship and no annotations are necessary.